# Ember App test fails in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, phantomjs

For some some reason my ember app's test fails in PhantomJS, but works in Chrome. Unable to figure out why, PhantomJS could not find my app's resolver.None of these issue are present when the test are ran in chrome.

I get the following error.

```
Error: Could not find module `my-app/resolver` imported from `my-app/tests/helper
s/resolver` at http://localhost:4212/assets/vendor.js, line 173
Error: Assertion Failed: The tests file was not loaded. Make sure your tests index.html
 includes "assets/tests.js". at http://localhost:4212/assets/vendor.js, line 16463
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.length') at http://localhost:42
12/assets/test-loader.js, line 115
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.length') at http://localhost:42
12/assets/test-loader.js, line 115
```

Other information:

```
ember-cli: 2.5.0
node: 0.12.14
os: darwin x64
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "repository": "",
  "description": "Small description for my-app goes here",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ember server",
    "build": "ember build",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "body-parser": "1.12.4",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "2.4.2",
    "broccoli-jscs": "0.0.22",
    "connect-restreamer": "1.0.2",
    "ember-ajax": "0.7.1",
    "ember-cli": "2.5.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "5.1.6",
    "ember-cli-blanket": "0.9.4",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.4.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "1.2.0",
    "ember-cli-document-title": "0.2.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.2.4",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.4.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "1.4.0",
    "ember-cli-release": "0.2.8",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth-cookie-store": "0.8.0",
    "ember-cli-sri": "2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "1.2.0",
    "ember-data": "2.5.0",
    "ember-disable-proxy-controllers": "1.0.1",
    "ember-export-application-global": "1.0.5",
    "ember-load-initializers": "0.5.1",
    "ember-resolver": "2.0.3",
    "ember-sinon": "0.3.0",
    "esprima-fb": "15001.1.0-dev-harmony-fb",
    "express": "4.12.3",
    "glob": "4.5.3",
    "liquid-fire": "0.23.0",
    "loader.js": "4.0.1",
    "morgan": "1.5.3",
    "<mycustommod1>": "file:node_modules/mycustommod1",
    "<mycustommod2>": "file:node_modules/mycustommod2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "1.0.3",
    "ember-cli-sass": "5.3.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `"ember-cli-blanket": "0.9.4"`, worked for me.

Comment: I cannot remove blanket. Since I need coverage report for my files. Will anyways give a try , to see if blanket causing any issue